# How to comment out, a commented code

Tags: c, comments

Lets say in a case like this:

```
if(a==true){
  /*DOC THIS DOES 
  VERY
  IMPORTANT
  STUFF
  */
  a=false;
}
```

I want to comment out the whole if case out including the documentation. I will later reopen and use it.

How can this task be achieved?

(I think this is a general problem but right now I am working on Xcode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is language dependent obviously, but since you seem to be using C, you can use preprocessor directives.

```
#ifdef __BOGUS__
if(a==true){
   /*DOC THIS DOES 
   VERY
   IMPORTANT
   STUFF
   */
   a=false;
   } 
#endif
```